# Angular 14 & Typescript: Can you get the class property type that are decorated by @Input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, types, decorator

Can you get only property types that are decorated by `@Input` in a class.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-date-column',
  templateUrl: './date-column.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./date-column.component.scss'],
})
export class DateColumnComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() data!: string | Date; // I want this
  @Input() num: number; // I want this
  public st: string; // Don't want this
}

type myType<T> = DoSomethingHereToGet //-> {data: string |Date; num: number }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly but you can create getters and setters? https://andrew-morozw.medium.com/using-getters-and-setters-in-typescript-and-angular-d478829461c8

Comment: @LeroyMeijer I think OP would like a type declaration that returns all properties from a given type that are decorated with a `@Input`

Comment: @MikeS. is right. I just want the interface composed of property keys that are decorated by @Input() and their corresponding types.

Comment: I really doubt that you can do that with typescript type. You could manually get keys that you are interested in with `Pick<DateColumnComponent, 'data' | 'num'>`, but it's not exactly what you want

Comment: Yeah, the compiler knows the fields but it's most likely impossible in the "typescript world" :(